# JavaFX editable tableview: How to change size and css of the TextField inside of TableCell?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I have changed height of the TableRows in css and it is working well, but how can I change the size of the TextField in side of TableCell which should be editable. Hopefully the picture can explain my problem:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the css of the text field just after it's created by adding css.  You can also change some things in code.

```
    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setStyle("-fx-padding 1px 1px 1px 1px;-fx-font-size: 10pt;");
        //or another way
        textField.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,5));
        textField.setFont(new Font(8));
```

You could also set the style class using `textField.getStyleClass().add("my-textfield");` and then create styles in your stylesheet for the program using `.my-textfield{css stuff...}`

I think the best idea is to not change the row size but to change the font.  The row height then changes automatically.  You can even change the font in your whole application by adding a stylesheet with `.root{ -fx-font-size:12pt;}` to the scene.

The [Oracle sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#JFXUC376) has a custom editing cell, example 12-11.  That is where the TextField gets created.

If you use `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn` you can style it using .text-field-table-cell

```
.text-field-table-cell{
    -fx-font-size:15pt;
    -fx-background-color: pink;
}
```

That will style all cells even before they are being edited.  If you only want styles in the edit state use  `.text-field-table-cell .text-field{` .  And they don't have to be pink:)

Comment: This is not actually answring to my question. I know how to change css of the TextField, but when I'm using TableView component which is editable and need to change css and size of the TextField which is opened inside to TableCell when you are editing table values, I don't know how to change that.

Comment: You say you have an editable text field.  You need to use a custom edit cell.  I'll post the link.

Comment: I just looked at the other way to edit cells using `TextFieldTableCell` and it has a style class.  I'll post a bit more.